# How do I format a number in Excel so the decimal appears in a specific spot?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two sets of numbers that correspond to the minimum and maximum values of an interval. In the database that I am pulling this data from, the numbers are formatted without decimal places, like 680, 1090, or 520000. I want to format them as I input them into an Excel file for a different project.

The first should be formatted as something like:

- 680 => 0.0680
- 1090 => 0.1090

The second set should be formatted like:

- 520000 => 52.0000
- 728750 => 72.8750

Is there a way I can set a column to have formatting that automatically converts the un-formatted number to one with a decimal in the right spot?

Thank you!

edit: reformatted my examples so they were easier to read :)

Comment: This is called Number Format. A good phrase to Google to learn how this works would be "Excel number format documentation". Enjoy.

Comment: @AlexM Yes that is what I needed. I just used division and then reformatted the output so they are correct.  Thanks for your help :)